# Front end applications for examining/digging through a SQL Analysis Services Mining Model

Tags: sql-server, data-mining, ssas

I currently use Excel and SQL Server Business intelligence studio to browse my models, but I've been searching high and low for a decent, moderately user-friendly front end application that can be used for trudging through a SSAS Mining Model.

I understand how to use the predictions for specific purposes (such as integrating with call queues and such) but the higher-ups are wanting to use the mining model in a more ad-hoc sense.

What applications are available for browsing a mining model and which ones have you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an ASP.Net Web page using the controls here:

http://msftasprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005!Data%20Mining%20Web%20Controls%20Library

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and select Analysis Service under the Server Type.

Comment: This is the way that I currently browse the models, I'm looking for a... Third Party tool.